# I permanently changed my PATH variable by mistake, and I am unable to login now. How to change my PATH variable to default?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I used `sudo -H gedit /etc/environment` command on terminal to permanently change my PATH variable.

To correct it, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, and used `export PATH` command, but access was denied.

Many commands (including `sudo` and `nano`) are not recognized as the new PATH variable doesn't have `/usr/bin`. I am new to Linux commands.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Also make backups when editing system files. Then you are just 1 `mv` away from restoring it ;)

Comment: Please do not crosspost; your question fits Ask Ubuntu better than it fits Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/nano /etc/environment
```

Comment: In fact `/usr/bin/sudo nano /etc/environment` should be sufficient (since `sudo` uses its own `secure_path` in place of `PATH`)

Comment: @steeldriver: Ah, right, sounds plausible. Please feel free to edit, if you are sure. (I'm disinclined to test...)

Answer (score 8):

Possible methods:

- 1st try to log in using a TTY (control-alt-f1).
- If that does not work boot from a live DVD.

and then use

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

from command line and edit out your mistake. Save and reboot to test what you did is correct.

---

In case you need it:

```
 $ more /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Comment: I tried "sudo -H nano /etc/environment" command, and this was the response:  'sudo' is  available in 'usr/bin/sudo'. The command can't be located because 'usr/bin'is not included in PATH variable.

Comment: Hey thanks,  I used absolute paths for sudo and nano and solved it! :)