# Problem in installing maven ('/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable)

Tags: command-line, software-installation, sudo, environment-variables, maven-3

When I install maven 3.5.4 in my Linux platform I face this error:

```
$ sudo export PATH=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin
Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
sudo: command not found
```

I also tried `export PATH=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin`, but it didn't work.

Comment: 1) your user isn't include inside `sudoers` 2) probably your command haven't execution permission

Comment: While @damadam's response is the most probable reason why you weren't able to run sudo, you can still try to call it as `/usr/bin/sudo`. See if this results in a short list of sudo options or it gives you some other error.

Comment: Yet, it is strange that you were not able to update your regular user's path. Unless you intended to overwrite the previous path, the actual command should read `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin`. This should append your maven path to the end of the user's current path.

Comment: Are you sure that your maven is successfully installed? Try `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin/mvn -version`. If maven is installed correctly, this should give you the version information.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What's your Ubuntu release (check with `lsb_release -a`)? How are you trying to install Maven? Who told you to run the (nonsensical) command `sudo export`? Please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information. It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: FYI  `sudo` cannot be used to execute a builtin shell command such as `export`. See for example [Why won't “sudo cd” work?](https://superuser.com/questions/241129/why-wont-sudo-cd-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already changed your path. I can reproduce your error in a trivial way...

```
$ PATH=/some/path
$ sudo uname -r
Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH
 environment variable.
sudo: command not found
```

Ordinarily, you can fix this most easily by closing the terminal and opening a new one, since the change to PATH only holds for this shell and its children. Otherwise, run `source /etc/environment` if you have not edited `/etc/environment`.

If that does not work, it means you changed PATH in a configuration file somewhere, such as `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/environment`, and you will have to find the line that does that and change it. You will have a line like this

```
PATH=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin
```

This means that the only directory where the shell will search for commands/programs to run is `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin`. The change to PATH should be in `~/.profile` and should be like this:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin"
```

Adding `$PATH:` to the start means your existing PATH, which includes `/usr/bin` and all the other places where essential commands are found, will be included.

If you have changed `/etc/environment`, undo your changes if you saved a backup, or replace what you added there with the original content:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Note that you can still access commands that are not in PATH [using full paths](https://askubuntu.com/a/803281/527764), for example:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/nano /etc/environment
```

Also note that you do not need `export` to change PATH, because it is already exported. Neither do you need `sudo` to assign to your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

To export the PATH you don't need to use `sudo`.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
root@CVR:/# echo $PATH
```

[image]

```
root@CVR:/# export PATH=/usr/bin
root@CVR:/# 
root@CVR:/# echo $PATH
/usr/bin
```

Comment: You are root in this example, so you don't need `sudo` for anything unless you want to explicitly run a command as a user *other than* root. Indeed you do not need `sudo` to `export PATH`, (or to assign to it) and in fact [you cannot use `sudo` to run such commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053411/problem-in-installing-maven-usr-bin-is-not-included-in-the-path-environment#comment1721966_1053411) but you do not need to `export` `PATH` anyway because except in very exceptional situations it is already in the environment