# My System is failed to unlocked

Tags: xubuntu, environment-variables, system, paths, unlock

I mistakenly change my variable path of my xubuntu 18.04, i have tried many options found in this platform but is not working for me.
Please i need an urgent help [Screenshotof my tty4 console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUlzw.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I permanently changed my PATH variable by mistake, and I am unable to login now. How to change my PATH variable to default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803267/i-permanently-changed-my-path-variable-by-mistake-and-i-am-unable-to-login-now)

Answer (score 0):

You can set default environment in your current session by following command.

```
source /etc/environment
```

After that you should be able to run command under `/usr/bin`.
You can backup your current profile and create new default profile for fixing issue.

```
mv -v ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc_backup && mv -v ~/.profile  ~/.profile_backup
cp -v /etc/skel/{.bashrc,.profile} $HOME
```